# .net web forms edmx connection error

Tags: c#, webforms, connection

**The situation.**

No database in system.
EDMX file as xml simulte database.

**The need.**

I want to insert register on "database" (edmx file). Thats my code:

```
using (var context = new CepsaContainer())
{
      Usuarios usuario = new Usuarios();
      usuario.Username = "user";
      usuario.Password = "123456";
      context.AddToUsuariosSet(usuario);
      context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**The Problem.**

This line on .edmx file:

```
public CepsaContainer() : base("name=CepsaContainer", "CepsaContainer")
{
     this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
     OnContextCreated();
}
```

generate exception:
*The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.*

There is no database so i think that i dont need any connectionstring on my Web.config. Whats configuration is missing?

Thats my first proyect on ASP NET Web Forms so really thanks if someone can help me

Comment: What's the app.config look like for the edmx project? Should have a connection string called CepsaContainer

Comment: thnx, thats the error i need to generate a database from edmx, this generate a database connectionstring on my web.config.